# Comparison of computational cost of sparse direct methods and sparse iterative methods

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, finite-element-method

Can someone give me some reference(book/article) in which the computational cost of sparse direct methods is compared with sparse iterative methods for solving the linear system of equations of the form:

$$
Ax=b
$$
with $A \in C^{NxN}$ and $x,b \in C^{Nx1}$, where the linear system is arising from the discretization of PDEs, for example, by finite element methods.

What I know is that for dense matrices the typical computational cost of direct methods is $O(N^3)$. I have read somewhere on internet that for sparse direct methods the computational cost is from $O(N^{1.5})$ to $Nlog(N)$., but what is the source of this claim. My experience of working with Umfpack is that it is much more expensive than $Nlog(N)$. Which direct solver has this computational cost and for which type of problem?

Comment: This is a very broad question with many, many potential answers depending on what aspects you are interesting in, say, flop count, parallel efficiency, communication avoiding algorithms, time-to-solution, many or a single right side to name but a few. You are likely to get answers which you will find more useful if you can narrow the scope a bit.

Comment: Carl Christian- I have tried to improve my question, thanks for your observations.

Comment: After having used direct solvers for years in a finite element context, I've been converted to iterative methods, for 3-D problems at least. The reason is explained in this document : [On solving a Cosmic Ray equation](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/zonwind/zonwind.pdf) . Skip to page 14 and read until page 18 .